# What causes the error: Can't resolve all parameters for EventsListComponent: (?)?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I am following along with a course on Pluralsight but am running into an issue.  I must say in advance that they recommend using an older version of the Angular CLI while I am using the most recent one.

Following along the module that touches the subject of dependency-injection I am receiving an error (Can't resolve all parameters for EventsListComponent: (?)) and the page refuses to load. I have been able to fix that but my solution I presume is not the correct way and I would like to know what the correct solution should be.

I've been looking around the internet but for some reason I must be overlooking something as I can not get it to work using only the @Injectable() decorator.

I got a file called event.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class EventService {
  getEvents() {
    return EVENTS;
  }
}
```

in which EVENTS is a const array

```
const EVENTS = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Angular Connect',
    date: '9/26/2036',
    time: '10:00 am',
    price: 599.99,
    imageUrl: '/assets/images/angularconnect-shield.png',
    location: {
      address: '1057 DT',
      city: 'London',
      country: 'England'
    }
  }
];
```

and which I register in app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    EventsAppComponent,
    EventsListComponent,
    EventThumbnailComponent,
    NavBarComponent
  ],
  providers: [EventService],
  bootstrap: [EventsAppComponent]
})
```

According to the course the following should inject the service into my component (but results in the mentioned error)

```
export class EventsListComponent {
  events: any[];
  constructor(private eventService: EventService) {
    // should be done in the onInit hook but that is the next step in the course
    this.events = this.eventService.getEvents();
  }
}
```

I can fix this changing the code as follows

```
export class EventsListComponent {
  events: any[];
  eventService: EventService;
  constructor(@Inject(EventService) eventService: EventService) {
    this.eventService = eventService;
    this.events = this.eventService.getEvents();
  }
}
```

I am confused about what I am doing wrong as I am doing that in my solution which the @Injectable() decorator should take care of.

What is cousing the error and how do I fix it in the correct way?

Comment: Just did and that did not solve it. Still results in the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue.

It seems to have something to do with one of the dependency's they use being outdated.

I solved it by using the default dependency structure generated when creating a new angular project. I then added the jquery dependency and ngf-bootstrap dependency manually.